# Embed a NavigationButton in a NavigationBar

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I add a NavigationButton in the NavigationBar the button doesn't do anything when I click on it.

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        Text("test")

    }
    .navigationBarItems(
        leading: NavigationButton(destination: SettingsView()) {
            Text("Settings")
        },
        trailing: Button(action: {}, label: { chatImage }))


}
```

Comment: Await the next beta.

Comment: @matt So do you think this is just a bug?

Comment: I don't know about "bug" but it's well known that this isn't working.

Comment: Are you sure you want a `NavigationButton` and not a `PresentationButton`?

Answer (score 1):

use instead of your code

```
.navigationBarItems(
    leading: NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
        Text("Settings")
    },
    trailing: Button(action: {}, label: { chatImage }))
```

You can't use NavigationButton any more cuz it's changed.